# Проблема при загрузке css и пути к файлу

Tags: html, css, golang

Я делаю веб проект, на го, используя templates. Страницы переключаюся при нажатие, но стили не применяются. Я попробовала все возможные пути, но даже если я могу перейти по нему в командной строке он не воспринимается в приложении.
Структура проекта:

```
-backend<br/>
--server <br/>
---server.go http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("../../frontend/static/"))))<br/>
-frontend<br/>
--static<br/>
--templates rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/style.css"
```

Не применяються стили к страницам. Выдает ошибку

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/static/css/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Если нажимаю на 'http://localhost:3000/static/css/style.css' выдает `404 not found`. Из-за этого подозреваю что проблема в пути к файлам, но как правильно указать не знаю.

Comment: у вас href неверно сконфигурирован. поэтому по этой ссылке вы ничего не получаете. у вас сервер выдает стили через ручку /static. значит, замените на `href="static/css/style.css"`. и убедитесь, что `localhost:port/static/css/style.css` выдает нужный css

Comment: В мои проектах нужно использовать href="~/static/static/style.css" это при условии что папка со стилем лежит в домашней директории. При этом никакой вложенности static в static нет.